# Can't create new user in Redmine

Tags: ldap, registration, redmine, ldapauth

I need to hide registration button in Redmine. If I `disabling` Self-Registrtation in Redmine, I'm trying to log in as a new user, I need write my number and middle name, after submit I had same page with:

```
Email can't be empty
Phone Number can't be empty
Middle name can't be empty
Name can't be empty
Surname can't be empty
```

If I change self registration to `automatic account activation` everything working fine

Ldap authentication settings

```
Name     = Test
Host     = test.domain.org
Port     = 389
Account  = cn=user ldap,cn=users,dc=test,dc=domain,dc=org
Password = <password>
Base DN  = cn=users,dc=test,dc=domain,dc=org

On-the-fly user creation = yes
Attributes
  Login     = sAMAccountName
  Firstname = givenName
  Lastname  = sn
  Email     = userPrincipalName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use on-the-fly user creation, make sure that Redmine can fetch from your LDAP all the required information to create a valid user.
For example, on-the-fly user creation won't work if you don't have valid email adresses in your directory.

Also, make sure you don't have any custom field marked as required for user accounts. These custom fields would prevent user accounts from being created on the fly.

Here you can find more information:

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineldap